# get distinct count from an array of each rows using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for distinct counts from an array of each rows using pyspark dataframe:
    input:
    col1
    [1,1,1]
    [3,4,5]
    [1,2,1,2]

```
output:
1
3
2  

I used below code but it is giving me the length of an array:
output:
3
3
4

please help me how do i achieve this using python pyspark dataframe.

slen = udf(lambda s: len(s), IntegerType())
count = Df.withColumn("Count", slen(df.col1))
count.show()

Thanks in advanced !
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For spark2.4+ you can use array_distinct and then just get the size of that, to get count of distinct values in your array. Using UDF will be very slow and inefficient for big data, always try to use spark in-built functions.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct

(welcome to SO)

```
df.show()

+------------+
|        col1|
+------------+
|   [1, 1, 1]|
|   [3, 4, 5]|
|[1, 2, 1, 2]|
+------------+

df.withColumn("count", F.size(F.array_distinct("col1"))).show()

+------------+-----+
|        col1|count|
+------------+-----+
|   [1, 1, 1]|    1|
|   [3, 4, 5]|    3|
|[1, 2, 1, 2]|    2|
+------------+-----+
```